# How to graph with style?

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to graph a 3d surface $ z=x^2-y^2 $as transparent with bold lines$ z=x^2 $ and $z=-y^2.$ How to do this?

Comment: do you mean you want to graph the function some application?

Comment: This _really_ depends on what graphing software you're using. Is it MATLAB? GeoGebra? Mathematica? Something else?

Comment: @Arthur I would like to use geogebra.

Comment: Bring up the 3D GeoGebra window. Type z = x^2-y^2 for the surface. Type Curve[t, 0, t^2, t, -3, 3] for z = x^2 (the first three variables are x, y, z values, the fourth is the parameter and -3 to 3 is the range of t). Type similar for your second curve. Adjust the properties of your 3 objects as required.

Comment: So Curve[0,t,-t^2,0, t, -3, 3] is z=-y^2:

Comment: Yes - do it in GeoGebra and see!

Comment: @Paul https://ggbm.at/Ka6q5wUj  would be nice to add a mesh grid to the surface.

Comment: You will need to do two sets of curves. The first set will be "parallel" to $z = x^2$ and take the form $z = x^2-n^2$ for integer n from -4 to +4 say (note that $y$ now has value n not 0). Look at the sequence command to see how to efficiently do this. Similarly for $z = n^2 - y^2$